# como envio de e-mail com PHP com IF no meio da mensagem?

Tags: php

Eu possuo um código que manda e-mail através do php
No meio dele preciso fazer a condição if, mas estou tendo erro de síntaxe, vou deixar meu código abaixo

```
    $message .= "<br>";

$message .= "<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><br /><strong>TERMO DE TRANSFERENCIA DE RESPOSNSABILIDADE DE BENS PATRIMONIAIS</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><br />Eu ".$responsavel_saida." , Loja:".$nroempresa.", Setor: ".$setor.", at&eacute; a presente data respons&aacute;vel pelos bens constantes no relat&oacute;rio em anexo, DECLARO esta transferindo a responsabilidade sobre os mesmo para a Loja: ".$nroempresa_destino.", Setor: ".$setor_destino.", que passara a ter a inteira responsabilidade pela guarda, uso, controle e conserva&ccedil;&atilde;o dos mesmos, respondendo tamb&eacute;m pelas quantidades.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style=\"text-align: right;\"><strong>Loja:</strong> ".$nroempresa.", <strong>Data:</strong>".$dtasaida."</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img alt=Embedded Image src='$signature' width=\"200px\" height=\"100px\"/></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><br /><br /><strong>Resp.pelo setor Sa&iacute;da: ".$responsavel_saida."</strong>&nbsp;</p>
<p><table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>N. Plaqueta </td><td>Descricao </td><td>Empresa </td><td>Setor</td></tr><tr>

if ($plaqueta1 == TRUE) {




<td>".$plaqueta1." </td><td> ".$descdetalhada." </td><td> ".$nroempresa." </td><td> ".$setor."</td></tr>

}
if ($plaqueta2 == TRUE) {




<td>".$plaqueta2." </td><td> ".$descdetalhada." </td><td> ".$nroempresa." </td><td> ".$setor."</td></tr>

}
```

acontece que os ifs aparecem no corpo da mensagem, fica feio

Comment: -1 pq? meu deus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se é disso que precisa:

```
$message .= "<br>";

$message .= "<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><br /><strong>TERMO DE TRANSFERENCIA DE RESPOSNSABILIDADE DE BENS PATRIMONIAIS</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><br />Eu ".$responsavel_saida." , Loja:".$nroempresa.", Setor: ".$setor.", at&eacute; a presente data respons&aacute;vel pelos bens constantes no relat&oacute;rio em anexo, DECLARO esta transferindo a responsabilidade sobre os mesmo para a Loja: ".$nroempresa_destino.", Setor: ".$setor_destino.", que passara a ter a inteira responsabilidade pela guarda, uso, controle e conserva&ccedil;&atilde;o dos mesmos, respondendo tamb&eacute;m pelas quantidades.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style=\"text-align: right;\"><strong>Loja:</strong> ".$nroempresa.", <strong>Data:</strong>".$dtasaida."</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img alt=Embedded Image src='$signature' width=\"200px\" height=\"100px\"/></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><br /><br /><strong>Resp.pelo setor Sa&iacute;da: ".$responsavel_saida."</strong>&nbsp;</p>
<p><table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>N. Plaqueta </td><td>Descricao </td><td>Empresa </td><td>Setor</td></tr><tr>";

if ($plaqueta1 == TRUE) {

    $message .= "<td>".$plaqueta1." </td><td> ".$descdetalhada." </td><td> ".$nroempresa." </td><td> ".$setor."</td></tr>";

}
if ($plaqueta2 == TRUE) {

    $message .= "<td>".$plaqueta2." </td><td> ".$descdetalhada." </td><td> ".$nroempresa." </td><td> ".$setor."</td></tr>";

}
```

> Leitura recomendada: [PHP: Operadores de Strings](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php)
>
> Relacionado: [PHP: Estruturas de controle - if](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: funcionou, obrigado

Comment: A comunidade recomenda que aceite a resposta como solução, ao invés de comentar "funcionou, obrigado"... Abração! ;)